# Получить QWidget из QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt5

Всем привет! 
Такой вопрос, как мне достать определенный виджет из лойаута.

Например у меня есть такая конструкция:

```
QHBoxLayout * pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(parent);
QRadioButton * item = new QRadioButton(parent);
QPushButton * button = new QPushButton(parent);
pLayout->addWidget(item);
pLayout->addWidget(button);
layout->addLayout(pLayout);
```

И мне нужно достать из этой конструкции радиобаттон, например так:

```
for (size_t i = 0, sz = N; i < sz; ++i)
{
    QWidget * selectorWidget = layout->itemAt((int)i)->widget();
}
QRadioButton* item  = qobject_cast<QRadioButton*>(selectorWidget);
```

Comment: ну задали бы вопрос новый. В каждом `QObject` есть `objectName()`, вы можете при создании объекта его задать, и при считывании из `layout` проверить, совпадает ли он с тем что вам нужно. Пример как вы написали в `item` будет после каста то `nullptr` то `QRadioButton`

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавьте в `QVBoxLayout` `QHBoxLyaout`, а уже в него что нужно.
2. Возьмите указатель на `QPushButton` который вы разместили в `QGridLayout` и выставите ему свойство (`btn->setEnabled(false)` вроде)